# How to tell the Gem File to use a specific local copy of a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, path, rubygems

Say I have a gem living happily at:

1. `/MyPath/MyGem.gem`

And I want to use the local and unique gem rather than a gem version from Github, or wherever it fetches it from.

How do I specify I want to use `gem "mygem"` from `/MyPath/MyGem.gem`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try, in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem "mygem", :path => "/MyPath/MyGem.gem"
```

Note that it's probably best to use a relative link in there, like:

```
gem "mygem", :path => "vendor/MyPath/MyGem.gem"
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. It tries to interpret :path as a directory path.

Comment: Try removing the `.gem` bit in the path.

Comment: you have to reference the entire folder, ie the one with the .gem inside it.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using `gem 'gemname', :path => "/your/path/here"`
It is very useful when you are building local gems for development or if you have your own fork of a gem locally.

Answer (score 3):

I did it like Jits said but It didn't work. It seems that rails expect a folder path instead of a .gem path.

It worked for me

```
gem "mygem", :path => "vendor/gems/mygemfolder/"
```

If it works for you but you can't deploy to heroku (like it happened to me) you need to specify the version of the gem:

```
gem 'mygem', '= x.x.x', :path => 'vendor/gems/mygemfolder/'
```