# How to specify version of a local gem in Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a local gem and a rails app that uses the local gem.

Is there a way to specify a specific version of the gem?

I know that 'rake install' generates *.gem in /pkg directory of the gem. But I don't know how to use it.

Here's how I use it now:

```
In Gemfile:
gem 'mygem', path: '~/shared/mygem'
```

Thanks.

Sam

Edit:

I think my question is almost a duplicate of [How to tell the Gem File to use a specific local copy of a gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220664/how-to-tell-the-gem-file-to-use-a-specific-local-copy-of-a-gem).

I just need to know how to specify a specific version of a local gem.

Comment: This helps: http://blog.func-i.com/post/41108636143/bundler-gets-better-local-gem-support

Answer (score 1):

```
In Gemfile:
gem 'mygem', path: '~/shared/mygem', branch: 'branch name'
```

Or use ref: 'commit number' if your version is in a specific commit

Answer (score 0):

To specify versions, or more specifically, a range of versions, you use operators like you would in ruby code.

The operators should be:

`>=` , `<=` , `=`, or `~>`

Ranges allow that it may not be possible to match the exact version number (especially true for Windows-specific gem builds).

The pessimistic operator (`~>`) is often considered the best choice, as it stays within the same dot-range as the build you are using (1.0.4 would never reach 1.1.0, but could use anything between).

An example of the gemfile syntax:

```
gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.4.4'
```

or

```
gem 'uglifier', '= 1.3.0'
```

Comment: But for the local gem, bundler can find the latest version but not the past versions. When I speficy the version to '0.0.3', the bundler says "Could not find gem 'mygem (= 0.0.3) ruby' in source at ../shared/mygem. Source contains 'mygem' at: 0.0.4".

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it should not be able to find 0.0.3 because you have 0.0.4 installed. Do you have 0.0.3? If so, maybe you need to do something like: `gem 'mygem', '= 0.0.3', :path => 'path/to/gemfolder/'` - to specify the folder 0.0.3 is in. It seems like rails expects a directory as opposed to the file path.