# Specifying target path in Gemfile for bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to fetch a gem from remote source and then extract it into vendor/engines

Is there a way to do this using bundler and Gemfile?
Is there a way to specify target directory for a gem?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by

```
gem "mygem", :path => "vendor/MyPath/MyGem.gem"
```

refer, [How to tell the Gem File to use a specific local copy of a gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220664/how-to-tell-the-gem-file-to-use-a-specific-local-copy-of-a-gem)